# Continue even if key does not exist in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

My application loads some parameters from a json object which in turn is interpreted as a dictionary. I set several class variables to the value of the keys, e.g

```
try:
   self.a = mydict["field_a"]
   self.b = mydict["field_b"]
   self.c = mydict["field_c"]
```

depending on the json file (I get several different objects from it), some times the dictionary will not contain key "field_b". This doesn't matter, so I handle the `KeyError` exception and just continue the program flow.

Now, when a `KeyError` happens, it jumps out and skips checking for "field_c" if "field_b" does not exist. How can I force python to check for all fields, without having lots of `if(key["key"] is not None):` before pulling out the data?

Comment: how about using `dict.get()` it returns `None` if the key is not present, instead of throwing a `KeyError` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, I will accept that answer. Quite handy

Answer (score 7):

Use [dict.get](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm):

```
  self.a = mydict.get("field_a")
  self.b = mydict.get("field_b")
  .....
```

The default will be None which seems to match `if(key["key"] is not None`, if you want a different default value just pass whatever value you want as the default as the second arg to get `mydict.get("field_a","whatever")`.

If you want to keep self.a etc  as is if they don't appear in the dict use them as the default value:

```
 self.a = mydict.get("field_a", self.a )
```

Comment: Wow, that easy huh. Will accept the answer in 10 mins.

Comment: Yep, that easy, it is python after all ;)

Comment: Coming from embedded C, I continue to be amazed.